# Performance for big query in SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-view

I have a big query for a view that takes a couple of hours to run and I feel like it may be possible to work on its performance "a bit"..

The problem is that I am not sure of what I should do. The query `SELECT` **39** values, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` **25** tables and each table could have up to a couple of **million rows**.

Any tip is good. Is there any good way to attack this problem? I tried to look at the actual execution plan on a test with less data *(took about 10 min to run)* but it's crazy big. Is there any general things I could do to make this faster? Do I have to tackle one small part at the time..?

Maybe there is just one join that slows down everything? How do I detect it? So what I mean for short, how do I work on a query like this?

As a said, all feedback is good. Is there some more information I need to show, tell me!

The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.something,
    A.somethingElse,
    B.something,
    C.somethingElse,
    ISNULL(C.somethingElseElse, '')
    C.somethingElseElseElse,
    CASE *** THEN D.something ELSE 0,
    E.something,
    ...
    U.something
FROM 
    TableA A 
JOIN 
    TableB B on ...
JOIN 
    TableC C on ...
JOIN 
    TableD D on ...
JOIN 
    TableE E on ...
JOIN 
    TableF F on ...
JOIN 
    TableG G on ...
...
JOIN 
    Table U on ...
```

Comment: No matter how long you wait for query plan - it's key to optimization. First of all, use indexes on fields used in join and where clauses. You might try working with stored procedures or subqueries that will limit results.

Comment: Thank you, good tip. There is no where clause but I will try to index the fields used in the join clause and see if it makes any difference. In what way can I work with sps and subqueries instead?

Comment: Take `TableA A JOIN TableB B on <B.X=A.X>`. Does an index exist on the `B.X` field? Or if that join condition joins on more than one field, do you have an index for those fields? Also, if you select only one column from the B table, you could have that index `INCLUDE` that field, so that the query can take the value from the index directly. Experiment with just those two tables, see what indexes are missing and create those, then work up to the whole query. Without more detail of the query that's about all I can say.

Comment: how many records is your expected output? a few rows, thousands or millions?

Comment: The expected output depends on the amount of data I have, which is constantly increasing, but right now it's about one million rows.

Comment: TableA, TableB.. TableX are real tables or there could be views or functions?

Comment: Mostly tables but these 25 joins include one function and one view.

Comment: ok, try to exclude the view and the function from the query, and test how it impact on performances. if there is big difference (as I think ) we can check how to improve the view and the function (i.e. function result can be indexed)

Comment: I've tried that and it sadly does not make such a big difference.

Comment: run same query with only `SELECT TableA.PK_Field` we need to know if problem is the list of columns selected (maybe a Text or Xml field..)

Comment: 1) the join cardinality, is most 1:1 or 1:n ? if you are selecting ~1m recs from 25 tables.. it is 25m recs to scan.. 2) all tables involved in join have columns in `SELECT`? if there are join used only to filter output we can try a different approach

Comment: Just selecting the ids (PK) reduced the time for me to about 50% of the total time on my test.

Every table does not have ~1m recs but maybe 1/3 of them does. And I'd say 75% of the tables are used in `SELECT`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130788/discussion-between-mtwstark-and-ankan).

Comment: use group by not distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break your problem into manageable pieces. If the execution plan is too large for you to analyze, start with a smaller part of the query, check its execution plan and optimize it.

There is no general answer on how to optimize a query, since there is a whole bunch of possible reasons why a query can be slow. You have to check the execution plan.

Generally the most promising ways to improve performance are:

**Indexing:**

When you see a a *Clustered Index Scan* or - even worse (because then you don't have a clustered index) - a *Table Scan* in your query plan for a table that you join, you need an index for your `JOIN` predicate. This is especially true if you have tables with millions of entries, and you select only a small subset of those entries. Check also the index suggestions in the execution plan.

You see that the index works when your *Clustered Index Scan* turns into an *Index Seek*.

**Index includes:**

You probably are displaying columns from your joined tables that are different from the fields you use to join (otherwise, why would you need to join then?). SQL Server needs to get the fields that you need from the table, which you see in the execution plan as *Key Lookup*.

Since you are taking 39 values from 25 tables, there will be very few fields per table that you will need to get (mostly one or two). SQL Server needs to load entire pages of the respecitive table and get the values from them.

In this case, you should [`INCLUDE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) the column(s) you want to display in your index to avoid the key lookups. This comes at an increased index size, but considering you only include a few columns, that cost should be neglectable compared to the size of your tables.

**Checking views that you join:**

When you join `VIEW`s you should be aware that it basically means an extension to your query (which means also of the execution plan). Do the same performance optimizations for the view as you do for your main query. Also, check if you join tables in the view that you already join in the main query. These joins might be unnecessary.

**Indexed views (maybe):**

In general, you can add indexes to views you are joining to your query or create one or more indexed views for parts of your query. There are some caveats though:

1. Indexed views take storage space in your DB, because you store parts of the data multiple times.
2. There are [a lot of restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) to indexed views, most notably in your case that `OUTER JOIN`s are forbidden. If you can transform at least some of your `OUTER JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s this might be an option.

When you join indexed views, don't forget to use `WITH(NOEXPAND)` in your join, otherwise they might be ignored.

**Partitioned tables (maybe):**

If you are running on the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server, you can partition your tables. That can be useful if the rows you join are always selected from a small subset of the available rows. You can make a partition for this subset and increase performance.

**Summary:**

Divide and conquer. Analyze your query bit by bit to optimize it. The most promising options are indexes and index includes. If you still have trouble, go from there.